# ElasticSearch retrieves documents slowly

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, bigdata, java

I'm using Java_API to retrieve records from ElasticSearch, it needs approximately 5 second to retrieve 100000 document (record/row) in Java application.

Is it slow for ElasticSearch? or is it normal?

Here is the index settings:

[image]

I tried to get better performance but without result, here is what I did:

- Set ElasticSearch heap space to 3GB it was 1GB(default) `-Xms3g` `-Xmx3g`
- Migrate the ElasticSearch on SSD from 7200 RPM Hard Drive
- Retrieve only one filed instead of 30

Here is my Java Implementation Code

```
private void getDocuments() {
        int counter = 1;
        try {
            lgg.info("started");
            TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
                    .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

            SearchResponse scrollResp = client.prepareSearch("ebpp_payments_union").setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())                 
                    .setScroll(new TimeValue(1000))
                    .setFetchSource(new String[] { "payment_id" }, null)
                    .setSize(10000)
                    .get();

            do {
                for (SearchHit hit : scrollResp.getHits().getHits()) {
                    if (counter % 100000 == 0) {
                        lgg.info(counter + "--" + hit.getSourceAsString());
                    }
                    counter++;
                }

                scrollResp = client.prepareSearchScroll(scrollResp.getScrollId())
                        .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
                        .execute()
                        .actionGet();
            } while (scrollResp.getHits().getHits().length != 0);

            client.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

> I know that `TransportClient` is deprecated, I tried by
>   `RestHighLevelClient` also, but it does not changes anything.

Do you know how to get better performance?

Should I change something in ElasticSearch or modify my Java code?

Comment: is 5 sec consitent for each request and is it the only request you are making to your ES cluster?

Comment: Time to retrieve 100000 record changes from 3 to 7, there is only one request at a time

Answer (score 1):

Performance troubleshooting/tuning is hard to do with out understanding all of the stuff involved but that does not seem very fast. Because this is a single node cluster you're going to run into some performance issues. If this was a production cluster you would have at least a **replica** for each shard which can also be used for reading.

A few other things you can do:

- Index your documents based on your most frequently searched attribute - this will write all of the documents with the same attribute to the same shard so ES does less work reading (This won't help you since you have a single shard)
- Add multiple replica shards so you can fan out the reads across nodes in the cluster (once again, need to actually have a cluster)
- Don't have the master role on the same boxes as your data - if you have a moderate or large cluster you should have boxes that are *neither* master nor data but are the boxes your app connects to so they can manage the meta work for the searches and let the data nodes focus on data.
- Use "query_then_fetch" - unless you are using weighted searches, then you should probably stick with DFS.

Comment: Thanks for answer, as you see the index is not big it 15000000 million document 8GB, should i have several shards and replicas for this amount of data?

Comment: You should always (in a production box) have at least 1 replica shard for each primary. Other than that it's really down to your specific system but more is generally better.

Comment: Now I have 15 shard but the speed does not changed, ElasticSearch is running only on a 1 machine, Is it good Idea to have replicas when it runs only on a 1 machine?

Comment: No, although it should run pretty quickly off your SSD. My answers are more aimed at production systems where you need both redundancy and reliable performance. You may want to try creating a cloud based system to test and see if you continue to have perf issues.

Answer (score 1):

I see three possible axes for optimizations:

1/ sort your documents on _doc key :

> Scroll requests have optimizations that make them faster when the sort
>   order is _doc. If you want to iterate over all documents regardless of
>   the order, this is the most efficient option:

( [documentation source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) )

2/ reduce your page size, 10000 seems a high value. Can you make differents test with reduced values like 5000 /1000?

3/ Remove the source filtering

> .setFetchSource(new String[] { "payment_id" }, null)

It can be heavy to make source filtering, since the elastic node needs to read the source, transformed in Object and then filtered. So can you try to remove this? The network load will increase but its a trade :)

Comment: Thanks for answer, sort by _doc has decreased the retrieve time know its approx. 2 second. it's good, but I think that elastic can do more fast.

Comment: any luck on disabling source filtering and reducing the size?

Comment: reducing the size changes nothing from 1000 to 10000, if i set bellow 1000/500 it slows the query.  .setFetchSource gives better performance,  retrive 100000 document changes from 1  to 2 second